# Xamarin Realm DB Delete All Records

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a very short question, I have a project built with Xamarin. I am using realm db in this project. And what I want to do is delete all data on realm db whenever I press a button. I can do this in listview with item selected, but I want to delete all data with a single button.

Thank you in advance for your help. Stackoverflow has taught me a lot.

Comment: there are many, many existing questions and posts about deleting all records from a RealmDB.  Have you looked at any of them?

Comment: sorry i'm a little new to websites like stackoverflow and it didn't come to my mind i will be more careful thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using realm db in this project. And what I want to do is delete all data on realm db whenever I press a button. I can do this in listview with item selected, but I want to delete all data with a single button.

If you want to delete all Realm Db record , please take a look the following code.

My model,

```
public class Student : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
}
```

MainPage

```
 <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="listStudent">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding StudentName}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        <Button
            x:Name="Addbtn"
            Clicked="Addbtn_Clicked"
            Text="add data" />
        <Button
            x:Name="deletebtn"
            Clicked="deletebtn_Clicked"
            Text="delete all data" />
    </StackLayout>

public partial class Page30 : ContentPage
{
    
    public Page30()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       
    }

    private void Addbtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var realmDB = Realm.GetInstance();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            Student item = new Student()
            {
                StudentID = i,
                StudentName = "cherry " + i
            };
            realmDB.Write(() =>
            {
                realmDB.Add(item);
            });

        }

        List<Student> students = realmDB.All<Student>().ToList();
        listStudent.ItemsSource = students;
       
    }

    private void deletebtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var realmDB = Realm.GetInstance();
        
        realmDB.Write(() =>
        {
            realmDB.RemoveAll();
        });
        List<Student> students = realmDB.All<Student>().ToList();
        listStudent.ItemsSource = students;
    }
}
```